# Trimming Mysql last "AND" value

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario:

Here's my script:

```
set @p1 = '01';
set @p2 = '02';
set @p3 = '03';
set @p4 = '04';
set @p5 = '05';
set @p6 = '';
set @p7 = '07';
set @p8 = '08';
set @p9 = '09';
set @p10 = '010';
set @p11 = '11';

SET @VAL =  concat_ws(' ',
IF(@p1='','',concat_ws(' ','F1=', @p1,' AND')),
IF(@p2='','',concat_ws(' ','F2=', @p2,' AND')),
IF(@p3='','',concat_ws(' ','F3=', @p3,' AND')),
IF(@p4='','',concat_ws(' ','F4=', @p4,' AND')),
IF(@p5='','',concat_ws(' ','F5=', @p5,' AND')),
IF(@p6='','',concat_ws(' ','F6=', @p6,' AND')),
IF(@p7='','',concat_ws(' ','F7=',@p7,' AND')),
IF(@p8='','',concat_ws(' ','F8=', @p8,' AND')),
IF(@p9='','',concat_ws(' ','F9=', @p9,' AND')),
IF(@p10='','',concat_ws(' ','F10=', @p10,' AND')),
IF(@p11='','',concat_ws(' ','F11=', @p11))
);

SET @res = CONCAT_WS(' ','Select ','@VAL');

PREPARE STMT FROM @res;
EXECUTE  STMT;
```

Result:

```
F1= 01  AND F2= 02  AND F3= 03  AND F4= 04  AND F5= 05  AND  F7= 07  AND F8= 08  AND F9= 09  AND F10= 010  AND F11= 11
```

This sample code is working fine but my problem is this example:

```
set @p1 = '01';
set @p2 = '02';
set @p3 = '03';
set @p4 = '04';
set @p5 = '05';
set @p6 = '';
set @p7 = '07';
set @p8 = '08';
set @p9 = '09';
set @p10 = '010';
set @p11 = '';

SET @VAL =  concat_ws(' ',
IF(@p1='','',concat_ws(' ','F1=', @p1,' AND')),
IF(@p2='','',concat_ws(' ','F2=', @p2,' AND')),
IF(@p3='','',concat_ws(' ','F3=', @p3,' AND')),
IF(@p4='','',concat_ws(' ','F4=', @p4,' AND')),
IF(@p5='','',concat_ws(' ','F5=', @p5,' AND')),
IF(@p6='','',concat_ws(' ','F6=', @p6,' AND')),
IF(@p7='','',concat_ws(' ','F7=',@p7,' AND')),
IF(@p8='','',concat_ws(' ','F8=', @p8,' AND')),
IF(@p9='','',concat_ws(' ','F9=', @p9,' AND')),
IF(@p10='','',concat_ws(' ','F10=', @p10,' AND')),
IF(@p11='','',concat_ws(' ','F11=', @p11))
);

SET @res = CONCAT_WS(' ','Select ','@VAL');

PREPARE STMT FROM @res;
EXECUTE  STMT;
```

Result:

```
F1= 01  AND F2= 02  AND F3= 03  AND F4= 04  AND F5= 05  AND  F7= 07  AND F8= 08  AND F9= 09  AND F10= 010  AND
```

I need to remove if the last word is `AND` from the result.

Any better idea is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to put the `AND` into the outer `CONCAT_WS` and make the result of the `IF` statements `NULL` when the variable is empty, since `NULL` values will be ignored by `CONCAT_WS` (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)). This will also allow simplifying the inner `CONCAT_WS` to `CONCAT`:

```
set @p1 = '01';
set @p2 = '02';
set @p3 = '03';
set @p4 = '04';
set @p5 = '05';
set @p6 = '';
set @p7 = '07';
set @p8 = '08';
set @p9 = '09';
set @p10 = '010';
set @p11 = '';

SET @VAL =  concat_ws(' AND ',
IF(@p1='',NULL,concat('F1=', @p1)),
IF(@p2='',NULL,concat('F2=', @p2)),
IF(@p3='',NULL,concat('F3=', @p3)),
IF(@p4='',NULL,concat('F4=', @p4)),
IF(@p5='',NULL,concat('F5=', @p5)),
IF(@p6='',NULL,concat('F6=', @p6)),
IF(@p7='',NULL,concat('F7=',@p7)),
IF(@p8='',NULL,concat('F8=', @p8)),
IF(@p9='',NULL,concat('F9=', @p9)),
IF(@p10='',NULL,concat('F10=', @p10)),
IF(@p11='',NULL,concat('F11=', @p11))
);

SET @res = CONCAT_WS(' ','Select ','@VAL');

PREPARE STMT FROM @res;
EXECUTE  STMT;
```

Output:

```
F1=01 AND F2=02 AND F3=03 AND F4=04 AND F5=05 AND F7=07 AND F8=08 AND F9=09 AND F10=010
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4C3vNoHyEvzB4yQQyDbXVW/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [TRIM()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function to first remove trailing spaces and then remove the trailing `AND`

```
SET @VAL = TRIM('AND' FROM TRIM(@VAL));

SET @res = CONCAT_WS(' ','Select ','@VAL');
```

Demo: [Fiddle Demo #1](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sPPnZEtgtgoJh2wvkWZSUJ/0)

Another way is to store your data into a (temporary) table and use the `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function with `' AND '` as SEPARATOR. Empty values will be filtered in the WHERE clause:

```
set @p1 = '01';
set @p2 = '02';
set @p3 = '03';
set @p4 = '04';
set @p5 = '05';
set @p6 = '';
set @p7 = '07';
set @p8 = '08';
set @p9 = '09';
set @p10 = '010';
set @p11 = '';

create temporary table k_v(
  k varchar(10),
  v varchar(10)
);

insert into k_v(k, v) values
  ('F1',   @p1),
  ('F2',   @p2),
  ('F3',   @p3),
  ('F4',   @p4),
  ('F5',   @p5),
  ('F6',   @p6),
  ('F7',   @p7),
  ('F8',   @p8),
  ('F9',   @p9),
  ('F10', @p10),
  ('F11', @p11);

SET @VAL = (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(k, '= ', v SEPARATOR ' AND ')
  FROM k_v
  WHERE v <> ''
);

SET @res = CONCAT_WS(' ','Select ','@VAL');

PREPARE STMT FROM @res;
EXECUTE  STMT;
```

Demo: [Fiddle Demo #2](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ab7nzx3gmt4M6xuVe15vT8/0)

Depending on where your data (@p1, .. @pN) come from, there might be a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for the idea @PaulSpiegel.